# How to send pull request when git histories are different but changes are same?

Tags: git, github

This is my origin and upstream initially,

`upstream: --A--B--C--D--`

`origin: --A--B--C--D--E--F`

I made a pull request to upstream and started working further,

`origin: --A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--`

Now, the repository owner squashed my commits and now my upstream looks like,

`upstream: --A--B--C--D--EF--`

I want to make a pull request again, but how can I do that because git thinks commits E, F and EF are different? This thing has happened to me many times and I always end up messing my git history. Can someone please tell me the right way to do it? I already tried doing rebase, squash and different things but that never worked.May be my way of doing them could be wrong. I can't even think of an appropriate title for my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You will want to use `git rebase --onto`.  Using it correctly is a bit tricky, especially since you will need to force-push to your own fork.

#### Long

> I want to make a pull request again, but how can I do that because git thinks commits E, F and EF are different?

They *are* different.

Remember, the "true name" of a commit is its raw hash ID.<sup>1</sup>  The hash ID of E is different from those of both F and EF; all three are separate, unique commits.  It does not matter that EF is the result of squashing E and F (well, it matters to *you;* the problem is that it doesn't do any good to *Git* so Git can't / won't help you here).

We need to understand that Git is distributed, and the way Git achieves this distribution is to give out copies of commits, identified by their hash IDs.  Each commit itself is mostly a standalone snapshot, except that each commit records the hash ID of its *parent* commit.  A *name*, whether it's a branch name like `master` or `develop` or a remote-tracking name like `origin/master` or `upstream/master`, is a Git device for remembering one specific  commit.  That one commit remembers another, previous (parent) commit, and the parent remembers *its* parent, and so on.  So when we look at any one particular repository—yours on your laptop, for instance, we can draw out the commit graph:

```
A  <--B  <--C ... <--H   <--master
```

The *name* `master` stores the actual hash ID of commit `H`.  `H` stores the ID of `G`, which stores the ID of `F`, and so on all the way back to `A`.  (If `A` is the very first commit in the repository, it has no parent, and this lets Git stop moving backwards.)

Git thus need a *name* to find the *last* commit—what Git calls the *tip* of the branch—and Git then uses each commit to work backwards through history.  History itself is simply *all the commits Git can reach by starting at all the names you have, and working backwards*.

When we connect any two different Git repositories, we have one of them send to the other any commits that the sender has that the receiver doesn't, along with a name by which the receiver can identify the tip commit.  So if we start with:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

in one Git repository, and have another empty Git call this up and receive from it, the empty Git gets the `A-B-C-D` sequence and the name `master`.  If the receiving Git is doing a `git fetch`, the receiver *renames* their `master` to `origin/master` or `upstream/master`, depending on whether we are doing `git fetch origin` or `git fetch upstream`.  If both `upstream` and `origin` have this `A-B-C-D` sequence and both identify their `D` by the name `master`, and we fetch from *both*, we end up with:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- origin/master, upstream/master
```

(we get the commits themselves only once, since after we've obtained the sequence from either of the other two Git repositories, we have all the commits in question).

We can then make our own branch name `master` *also* pointing to `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master, upstream/master
```

then create our `E`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- origin/master, upstream/master
          \
           E   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and then create our `F` as before.  Now we can run `git push origin master` to have our Git call up the Git at `origin` and send it commits `E` and `F`, so that *that* Git—which, remember, has its own branch names; its `master` currently points to `D`—has these commits:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master [on origin]
          \
           E--F
```

Our Git then suggests that origin's Git should *change* its own `master` to point to commit `F`.  Origin's Git readily complies so that it now has:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master [on origin]
```

Your own Git updates your `origin/master` so that your repository, on your laptop, looks like this:

```
A-B--C--D   <-- upstream/master
         \
          E--F   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

Now you navigate the clicky buttons on GitHub and use the "make pull request" option.  What this does is to deliver commits `E` and `F` to the Git that you, on your laptop, call `upstream`, setting a somewhat hidden name, so that the *upstream* repository has this:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master [on upstream at GitHub]
          \
           E--F   <-- refs/pull/123/head [on upstream]
```

At this point, you depend on what whoever controls this GitHub repository does.

If they simply merged your commits, these two hash IDs would wind up in their own `master`.  But instead, they use the "squash and merge" clicky button.  This tells GitHub to *copy the effect* of the `E-F` chain to a new commit, that they add to their `master`.  Let's call this commit `EF`:

```
A--B--C--D--EF   <-- master [on upstream at GitHub]
          \
           E--F   <-- refs/pull/123/head [on upstream]
```

(Once the pull request is closed and dead long enough, the special `refs/pull/123/head` name probably goes away, and the two commits `E-F` get garbage collected.  These details are all up to GitHub.)

At this point, if you connect your laptop repository to the GitHub repository you call `upstream`, you will get any commits they have that you don't, and that's commit `EF`.  So now your repository has this:

```
A--B--C--D--EF   <-- upstream/master
          \
           E--F   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

If you add a new commit `G` now, or if you have already added it, it has commit `F` as its parent:

```
A--B--C--D--EF   <-- upstream/master
          \
           E--F   <-- origin/master
               \
                G   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and so on with `H`, if you create or have created it.  This is the situation you now find yourself in.

What you *don't* want to do is to try to deliver all of this to the Git repository you call `upstream`.  You cannot change commits `G` and `H`, but you can *copy* them to new commits.  Let's call them `G'` and `H'` since it will be very much *like* `G` and `H`.  The main difference between `G` and `G'` is that `G'` will have `EF` as its parent, and `H'` will have `G'` as its parent:

```
               G'-H'  <-- ???
              /
A--B--C--D--EF   <-- upstream/master
          \
           E--F   <-- origin/master
               \
                G--H   <-- ???
```

I've left the names here as question-marks.  The ideal thing for you is to make your name `master` point to this new copy `H'`.  If you do that, what name, if any, will remember the original `H`?  Git's general answer is that you probably don't *need* to remember the original chain: it's safe to just abandon it entirely.

#### Using `git rebase`

The command that copies one individual commit is `git cherry-pick`.  The command that, all at once, copies a whole *chain* of individual commits, and then *moves the branch name* the way we want, is `git rebase`.  But `git rebase` needs three pieces of information:

- What branch name should it move, once it's done copying all the commits that need to be copied?
- What commits actually need to be copied?
- Where do the copies *go*?

It gets these, by default, from *one* piece of information that you give it, and one that you imply.  You run:

```
git checkout master
git rebase other-name
```

and that tells it that the name to move is `master`, the target for the copy is the commit identified by `other-name`, and the commits to copy are those *reachable from* `master` (by starting at the tip and working backwards, in Git's usual fashion), but *not* any commits reachable from `other-name` (by starting at that tip and working backwards).  But at this point you have:

```
A--B--C--D--EF   <-- upstream/master
          \
           E--F   <-- origin/master
               \
                G--H   <-- master
```

so if we enumerate the commits reachable from `master` that are not reachable from `upstream/master` (where we want the copies to go), that's the entire `E-F-G-H` chain.  We want *only* `G-H`.

The solution is to use `git rebase --onto`, which lets us split the *target*—in our case, that's `upstream/master`—from the *commit limiter argument*, for which we want `origin/master`, or anything that identifies commit `F`.  Hence:

```
git checkout master
git rebase --onto upstream/master origin/master
```

which tells our Git: *select commits G and H; copy them to new commits that come after `upstream/master`; and then make our name `master` point to the last such copied commit.*  The result is:

```
               G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
              /
A--B--C--D--EF   <-- upstream/master
          \
           E--F   <-- origin/master
               \
                G--H   [abandoned]
```

Now we have a different problem.  Now we must have our Git deliver `G'` and `H'` to the Git on GitHub that we call `origin`—this part is easy enough—but then *force* that Git to change its `master`, which we call `origin/master`, to point to commit `H`, even though that makes it abandon commits `E-F`.  To do that, we can use `--force`:

```
git push --force origin master
```

This delivers the copied commits, then *commands* their Git—instead of requesting politely—to move its name `master` to point to commit `H'`, just like our own `master` does.  Assuming they obey the command,<sup>2</sup> they will change *their* repository to read:

```
A--B--C--D--EF--G'-H'  <-- master [on origin at GitHub]
```

Now we can use the clicky buttons on GitHub to make a pull request from this GitHub repository to the repository we call `upstream` on our laptop.  This pull request will deliver the `G'-H'` chain to them.  They will probably do one of those "squash and merge" operations again, so that they end up with:

```
A--B--C--D--EF--GH   <-- master [on upstream at GitHub]
```

after which we'll have to discard our `G` and `H` in favor of their combined `GH`, just as we had to do with our `E` and `F` in favor of their combined `EF`.

#### The principals involved here, or, why their process is a bit unfriendly

Any rebase or squash operation involves *copying* some commit(s) to some new commit(s).  The new commits have new, different hash IDs.

Any `git fetch` or `git push` operation involves copying commits from one repository to another.  These copied commits *share* their hash IDs.

What this means is that if you rebase or squash *your own* commits, specifically commits you've never given away to anyone else, everything is pretty simple.  You are the only one that ever had those hash IDs.  You now have newer, shinier, replacement commits, with new and different hash IDs, but you are the only one who had the old ones and you are the only one who has the new ones and you're *automatically* using the new ones.

If you rebase or squash *published* commits, though, you are making work for anyone else who had taken those commits and started using them.  They have those commits specifically *by* their hash IDs, and when you replace them with new-and-improved commits, you force *them* to replace *their* commits the same way.

In this case, they are the ones doing the replacing, and thereby forcing *you* to do some work.  They have replaced your `E-F` commit sequence with their squashed `EF` commit, so you must copy all your subsequent work.

This is not necessarily *bad*, but it's definitely more work for you than if they just took your commits as-is.  Had they done that, you could have delivered your `G-H` commits as-is as well.

---

<sup>1</sup>There is a secondary ID you can have Git compute, for most commits, that Git calls a *patch ID*.  The patch ID depends only on the *change* from the commit's (single) parent, to the commit.  That is, in effect, Git runs `git diff` on the parent and the commit—or runs `git show`, which does the same thing—and then strips away some other changeable information, such as line numbers and white-space, and computes a hash of the result.

The computed patch-ID is intended to work around simple cherry-pick operations.  It does not help with squashes.

<sup>2</sup>Since you control your GitHub repository—the one you call `origin` from your laptop—you can make sure you permit yourself to do this.  In general, whoever controls each repository also controls whether force-push is allowed.